# Function call jumps to the wrong function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static, stack-pointer

I am compiling a c++ static library in vs2008, and in the solution i also have a startup project that uses the lib, and that works fine.

But when using the lib in another solution i get an run-time check failure.
"The value of ESP was not properly saved across a functioncall"
Stepping through the code i noticed a function foo() jumping to bar() instead right before the crash. The functions in question are just regular functions and no function pointers.

Anyone has any clue what might be going on, and why it works when using the lib's from the same solution?

edit: the functions (methods) are part of a class, if that helps.

Comment: Are these functions actually methods?

Comment: Yes.. probably should have mentioned they were part of a class. You have an idea of might be causeing it?

Comment: This just happened to me in XCode, the answers have clarified why this happened. For me, it called a completely different header file's func, so I removed "virtual" and now it works, but recompiling is probably what went on to fix it. Strange error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forgive me for stating the bleeding obvious here, but...  I've seen this sort of thing happen many times before when object (.o) and header (.h) files get out of sync.  Especially with respect to virtual methods.

Consider:  The object file is compiled with header:

```
class Foo { virtual void f(); };
```

But then the header gets changed to:

```
class Foo { virtual void g(); virtual void f(); };
```

And for the next object file, the compiler's assumptions about where f() is located in the class's vtable are incorrect.

Oftentimes simply recompiling the world (everything!) will help.

Comment: This seemed to have been the case, the solution that got the error were using obsolete headers, thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @Mr.Ree, I encountered the same issue due to the same reason but not able to understand why this happens. If we have updated Static Libraries (header files may be older), static libraries should have correct addresses of functions then should the linker not get correct functions?

Comment: In my case - rebuild does not helped. What can I do now?

Comment: Okay - I've manged to resolve this issue thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350051/9223314
Short story: #define's were inconsistent between header file and actual implementation file.

Answer (score 7):

This is most probably due to incompatible calling conventions, where the library and the caller have different ideas about stack layout.

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58(VS.80).aspx) for more info.

Comment: using __cdecl (/Gd) in both solutions in the solution properies, so no difference between them there.

Comment: Hmm... What does the assembly code just before and after the call look like?

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure that you haven't selected
  in your project an old version of a
  library, I.e. (as Adam mentioned)
  you have selected an older debug
  version instead of a current release
  version or vica versa.
- You might need to rebuild.
- Also watch out for conditional compilation where a macro might get
  #defined or #undef'd at some point (The other solution may have some
  macros or projected #defines). Some
  times it might be helpful to delete
  your .lib .obj, and precompiled
  header caches with rebuild.
- There is a remote possibility that something is messed up in your IDE
  or project configuration, where you
  might need to recreate you project
  from scratch.
- I am not too familiar with MS VC, can you add the library's project
  file from the other solution?  For
  example, in Borland C++ Builder you
  can define project groups and
  build/make multiple projects, I
  always put the projects for the
  libraries I use in my program
  project group so everything gets
  up-to-date when I build.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're compiling in Debug mode and not Release mode.  If you attempt to debug a program in Release mode, the data you get back from the debugger will be garbage due to optimizations.

Comment: Compileing both solutions in Debug and Release. But did the stepping in Debug so shouldn't be any garbage there.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing such things when the struct member alignment (/Zp compiler switch) of the binaries was different. You could check that, too.

Setting it via #pragma pack rather than via project settings should be safer.

Comment: Both solutions have it set to the default value.